# multithreading - overwrite old value in queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have two threads: a producer and a consumer.  The producer periodically acquires information and provides it to the consumer.  The consumer wants only the most current copy of the information and will check it aperiodically and maybe a long intervals.

It seems like the simplest mechanism to facilitate this communication would be to create a `Queue.Queue(maxsize=1)`.  However, if the producer acquires new information before the old information is consumed it will block until the consumer uses the out of date information first.  Is there a way for the producer to overwrite the old information?

Is there a better threadsafe mechanism to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you Snild Dolkow.  Your suggestions are valuable.  In doing further research I did find a mechanism that seems intended for my particular situation.  A `collections.deque([iterable[, maxlen]])` would be thread-safe, discards old data when accepting new data, and according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> They are also useful for tracking transactions and other pools of data
>   where only the most recent activity is of interest.

With a `maxlen=1` the producer will always be able to write new data in.  When the consumer does a `pop()`, it will always get the most recent data.  If a `IndexError` is raised, indicating that the deque is empty, the consumer will continue to use the data it last received.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest fix would probably be to let the producer consume its old value, if there is one, before putting. You can use `Queue.get_nowait()` for this.

Stylistically, I'm not too keen on using a Queue for something only ever intended to hold one object. A normal Lock + a reference variable will make it more obvious what the code does.

Comment: That simple fix isn't thread safe, as in between the `take` and the `put` operations, the true consumer can preempt and find an empty queue.

Comment: In which case the consumer would block on the empty queue, handing the CPU back to the producer. The producer will then do the `put`, after which the consumer will be able to continue.

Comment: So true. Thanks for coming back and clarifying after all those years!

Comment: No worries -- you might've had some insight that I was lacking, and I always like an opportunity to learn! Glad we cleared it up. :)