# Architecture for data acquisition and processing

Tags: python, architecture

I am sharping up my Python skills and have started learning about websockets as an educational tool.
Therefore, I'm working with real-time data received every millisecond via a websocket. I would like to seperate its acquisition/processing/plotting in a clean and comprehensive way. Acquisition and processing are critical, whereas plotting can be updated every ~100ms.

**A)** I am assuming that the raw data arrives at a constant rate, every ms.

**B)** If processing isn't quick enough (>1ms), skip the data that arrived while busy and stay synced with A)

**C**) Every ~100ms or so, get the last processed data and plot it.

I guess that a *Minimal Working Example* would start like this:

```
import threading

class ReceiveData(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def receive(self):
        pass


class ProcessData(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def process(self):
        pass


class PlotData(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def plot(self):
        pass
```

Starting with this (is it even the right way to go ?), how can I pass the raw data from `ReceiveData` to `ProcessData`, and periodically to `PlotData` ? How can I keep the executions synced, and repeat calls every ms or 100ms ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your general approach with threads for receiving and processing the data is fine. For communication between the threads, I would suggest a producer-consumer approach. [Here is a complete example](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Producer_Consumer_using_Queue.php) using a `Queue` as a data structure.

In your case you want to skip unprocessed data and use only the most recent element. For achieving this, `collections.deque` (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)) might be a better choice for you - see also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949697/multithreading-overwrite-old-value-in-queue).

```
d = collections.deque(maxlen=1)
```

The producer side would then append data to the deque like this:

```
d.append(item)
```

And the main loop on the consumer side might look like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        item = d.pop()
        print('Getting item' + str(item))
    except IndexError:
        print('Deque is empty')
    # time.sleep(s) if you want to poll the latest data every s seconds
```

Possibly, you can merge the `ReceiveData` and `ProcessData` functionalities into just one class / thread and use only one deque between this class and `PlotData`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to go with `collections.deque` since it supports thread-safe and memory efficient appends & pops.