# Python threading - continuously save results from other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to get data from two sensor by means of threads. Assume, that these data are available by calling a corresponding funtion. These sensors should continuously be queried, but their values should only be saved when the time difference between two measurements is greater than a pre-defined threshold (only save data when the time difference to the last saved data is greater than 10 seconds). Since both threads for the data collection run in a while loop, I use another thread for saving the data. However, I have to somehow ensure that these data are available when saving. So the thread for saving has to wait for both other threads. Currently, I use `time.sleep()` which is working. But is there a better way to save the data of the two other threads?

```
import threading
import copy
import time

def thread1():
    global connected
    global data
    while connected:
        sensor_data = getSensorData()
        data['x'] = sensor_data.x
        data['y'] = sensor_data.y
        data['time'] = sensor_data.time 

def thread2():
    global connected
    global data
    while connected:
        other_sensor_data = getOtherSensorData()
        data['h'] = other_sensor_data.h

def save_data():
    global connected
    global data
    global results
    while connected:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if len(results) == 0 and len(data) > 0:
            results.append(copy.deepcopy(data))
        elif len(results) >= 1:
            if data['time'] - results[-1]['time'] >= 10:
                results.append(copy.deepcopy(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global connected
    global data
    global result

    connected = True
    data = {}
    if 'result' not in globals():
        result = []

    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread1)
    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread2)
    save_thread = threading.Thread(target=save_data)
    first_thread.start()
    second_thread.start()
    save_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use the build-in module **queue** which is designed to safely retrieve data from threads.

Using the LIFO functionality to create piles and then emptying them.

Here's a working example:

```py
import threading
import queue
import time

sensor_pile = queue.LifoQueue()
other_sensor_pile = queue.LifoQueue()


def getSensorData():
    time.sleep(0.05)

    class Test:
        x = "x " + str(time.time())
        y = "y " + str(time.time())
        time = time.time()
    return Test


def getOtherSensorData():
    time.sleep(0.01)

    class Test:
        h = "h " + str(time.time())
    return Test


def thread1():
    global connected
    while connected:
        sensor_pile.put(getSensorData())


def thread2():
    global connected
    while connected:
        other_sensor_pile.put(getOtherSensorData())


def save_data():
    global connected
    global results

    last_time = -float("inf")

    # Use other_sensor_pile.get() if the first h value should not be None
    h = None

    while connected:
        data = sensor_pile.get()  # Will wait to receive data.
        # As the main pile, the main while loop will keep it empty.

        try:
            # Update h to the latest value and then empty the pile.

            # get_nowait will get the data if it is available
            # or raise a queue.Empty error if it isn't.
            h = other_sensor_pile.get_nowait().h

            while True:
                other_sensor_pile.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        if data.time - last_time >= 0.2:  # Shortened for the sake of testing.
            last_time = data.time
            results.append({
                'time': last_time,
                'x': data.x,
                'y': data.y,
                'h': h
            })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global connected
    global results

    connected = True
    if 'results' not in globals():
        results = []

    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread1)
    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread2)
    save_thread = threading.Thread(target=save_data)
    first_thread.start()
    second_thread.start()
    save_thread.start()

    time.sleep(1)

    connected = False
    save_thread.join()
    second_thread.join()
    first_thread.join()
    for line in results:
        print(line)
```

With the example output:

```
{'time': 1627652645.7188394, 'x': 'x 45.7188', 'y': 'y 45.7188', 'h': 'h 45.7032'}
{'time': 1627652645.9584458, 'x': 'x 45.9584', 'y': 'y 45.9584', 'h': 'h 45.9584'}
{'time': 1627652646.1991317, 'x': 'x 46.1991', 'y': 'y 46.1991', 'h': 'h 46.1991'}
{'time': 1627652646.4394188, 'x': 'x 46.4394', 'y': 'y 46.4394', 'h': 'h 46.4394'}
{'time': 1627652646.6793587, 'x': 'x 46.6793', 'y': 'y 46.6793', 'h': 'h 46.6793'}
```

The emptying of the pile isn't very efficient and can cause problems if the data is put in faster than it can be emptied.

There may be some other methods to do this but I'm not sure how it would work. See:
[multithreading - overwrite old value in queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949697/multithreading-overwrite-old-value-in-queue)